# Is $l^2$ really a generalized Euclidean space?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, euclidean-geometry, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

Sorry for kind of clickbait title, but I am very interested in $l^2$ space - space of all square-summable (and ths convergent) sequences.

**First**, since I have read that $l^2$ is (with a pinch of salt) something like generalized Euclidean space or "sum of real lines" (really large sum though) - how can we really relate $l^2$ spaces and Euclidean spaces, particularly $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R^n}$? Can we really say statements like that?

**Second**, how does the "standard" topology on $l^2$ look like? Can we deliver it somehow from Euclidean standard topology?

**Third**, how are Hilbert spaces related to Euclidean generally? (Since $l^2(E)$ is isometric to any other Hilbert spaces, as I already asked about [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4214396/all-hilbert-spaces-are-isometric-to-l2e-how)).

I hope these questions are not too ambiguous - I am always interested in intuition more than the technical stuff). I can try to make them more precise.

Thank you for your insights.

Comment: $l^2=l^2(\mathbb{N})$ would be akin to "infinite dimensional Euclidean space".   $l^2(\mathbb{Z}  / n\mathbb{Z})$ is akin to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @Alan Because the sequences are like vectors, but with infinite coordinates right? So does that mean it really inherits all of the Euclidean properties, topology etc.?

Comment: Just edited the comment to give the version for finite.  And, umm, mostly?   Some things get weird at the infinite level.

Comment: @Alan Yes, that´s what my question was meant to be about. Like, it seemed suspicous that $l^2$ would be so similar to finite Euclidean...

Comment: What does it mean "Euclidean" anyway? Typically when we say "Euclidean" we think about something like this: lines (more generally linear subspaces), distance (metric/norm), angles (inner product), maybe some algebra, everything typically over $\mathbb{R}$. Hilbert spaces simply catch all of those notions quite well.

Comment: @Alan How is $l^2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ defined?

Comment: 3D Euclidean topology does not "inherit all properties" of 2D Euclidean topology, I am not even sure what "plane delivers 3D space" would mean. The dimensions are different, for one. Some figures cannot be superimposed in the plane but can be in 3D space, etc. But it is a natural generalization, and if you restrict 3D topology to a plane in space you'll get 2D Euclidean topology (and even distance). It is the same relation between $l^2$ and $n$D Euclidean spaces.

Comment: It would be square summable  $n$ tuples of (real or complex) numbers.   Since its finite, that would mean any such n -tuple, so those really are the same as $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Once you hit infinite dimensional stuff,  $l^2\subset \mathbb{R}^\infty$,  since there are lots of sequences that are not square summable.  $\mathbb{R}^\infty$'s default topology we'd talk about is the product topology,  in which open sets look like a finite cross product of open sets, with all the other coordinates being $\mathbb{R}$.  (So locally, everything is finite)

Comment: @Alan Ah, thank you, so the members of each sequence are sorted into n congruence classes right... "there are lots of sequences that are not square summable" - but $l^2$ has only these that ARE square summable

Comment: Correct @TerezaTizkova This is a good text on infinite dimensional vector spaces, including hilbert spaces.  https://www.textbooks.com/Introductory-Functional-Analysis-with-Applications-78-Edition/9780471504597/Erwin-Kreyszig.php?kpid=9780471504597U&kenshu=_k_CjwKCAjw3_KIBhA2EiwAaAAlivSH6g5zk5nQOSDUOhvxrVXqZKGLD54_XngaI_gfwJPs6OZNYpoZkBoClDUQAvD_BwE_k_&mcid=XKS-7564-41-1910-GoogleShopping-PRIDREPLACE-291&gclid=CjwKCAjw3_KIBhA2EiwAaAAlivSH6g5zk5nQOSDUOhvxrVXqZKGLD54_XngaI_gfwJPs6OZNYpoZkBoClDUQAvD_BwE

Comment: Look up Hilbert spaces. They are more general. They are vector spaces which have the notion of both length and angle. The lengths satisfy the Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linear $\ell^2$ has infinite sequences as vectors, namely precisely those that are square summable so that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i^2$ converges and this value being finite allows us to define a norm $\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i^2}$ which has the usual properties of a norm, like we know it from the Euclidean norm on $\Bbb R^n$. We can embed $\Bbb R^n$ into $\ell^2$ by $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \to (x_1, \ldots x_n, 0,0,0,\ldots)$ and we have an isometry, so the finite Euclidean spaces sit nicely inside this $\ell^2$. It also has an inner product (so we can talk about orthogonal vectors and such geometric concepts; we can define angles between vectors as usual etc.). The topology is also induced by the metric from this norm as $d(x,y)= \|x-y\|_2$ etc. It's also separable and complete like $\Bbb R^n$ is and locally convex, path-connected and all such nice things.

But in infinite dimensional spaces things do behave differently: no compact set can have a non-empty interior (so no local compactness) and if $K$ is compact (or even $\sigma$-compact) it can be shown that $\ell^2 \simeq \ell^2\setminus K$, in stark contrast with $\Bbb R^n$ where even removing a point leaves us with a non-homeomorphic result... The book about infinite-dimensional topology by Bessaga and Pelczynski is a classic intro to such facts.

Comment: Wonderful answer as always... Is the proof that $l^2 \simeq l^2\K$ found in the book by Bessaga and Pelczynski too, or do I find it elsewhere? That isomorphism seems interesting

Comment: $\ell^2$ being homeomorphic to $\ell^2\setminus K$ is in that book, indeed. I believe it was first shown by Anderson. An accessible treatment is in van Mill's book *infinite-dimensional topology, an introduction and prerequisites*, which is where I learnt it from (I have both books, and several more on this subject). @TerezaTizkova

Comment: Thank you! Couldnt find the book online, do you know whether it is accessible somewhere?

Comment: @TerezaTizkova that’s why you have to buy physical books. Invest! I bought them as soon as I had the money (and Engeking too of course)

Comment: Haha Im putting it on my Christmas list